# How do I correctly inject numeric values into JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Let's say that I have an ASP.NET page with JavaScript. Usually, injecting the result of server-side method/property calls into JavaScript is easy, as can be seen in the following common example:

```
var myUsernameControl = document.getElementById('<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>');
```

Everything works fine so far.

Now let's assume that I have a JavaScript expression that expects a *numeric* parameter instead of a string parameter, e.g.

```
var someValue = someJavaScriptFunction(<%= someServerSideProperty %>, true);
```

or

```
var someNumber = <%= someServerSideProperty %>;
```

**This works, but it yields a compile-time warning in Visual Studio ("Syntax error").** Apparently, the built-in JavaScript compiler sees this as

```
var someValue = someJavaScriptFunction(, true);
var someNumber = ;
```

and yields an error.

**How do I get rid of the warning?** I don't want to enclose `<%= someServerSideProperty %>` in single or double quotes, since this would change the semantics of the JavaScript code.

I'm sure that this is such a common problem that there *must* be a pretty, canonical solution to it, I just cannot find it...

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose your `<%= ... %>` tags with double quotes and prepend `+` sign to convert it to numeric value:

```
var someNumber = +"<%= someServerSideProperty %>";
```

Because

```
var a = +"10";
a === 10 // is true;
```

Comment: +1. Nice workaround, but I'll leave the question open to see if there's a prettier solution available.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is inefficient, but it get's rid of serverside and clientside errors and works:

```
var value = parseInt("<%= someServerSideIntVariable %>");
```

or MVC razor:

```
var value = parseInt("@Model.MyIntProp");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just define a dummy function in some common javascript file:

```
ServerValue = function (x) { return x; }
```

So in aspx or cshtml I can write:

```
var someNumber = ServerValue(<%= someServerSideProperty %>);
var someString = ServerValue('<%= someServerSideProperty %>');
var someValue = someJavaScriptFunction(
    ServerValue(<%= someServerSideProperty %>),
    true);
```